# Batch Program troubleshooting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I made this simple batch program to run certain functions or programs.

What I have so far:

```
@echo off
title HaxMenu
color 0c
cls
:menu
cls
title HaxMenu v.0.0.1 Alpha
echo HaxMenu v.0.0.1 Alpha
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo 1 - Begin HackBot
set /p do=
if %do%==1 goto hackbot
echo Please choose a valid #
pause>nul
goto menu
:hackbot
cls
echo Select Colors
echo Background
set /p first=
echo Font
set /p second=
pause>nul
set %colorhax%=%first%%second%
color %colorhax%
pause>nul
goto menu
```

Whenever I run the color function, I get an error that reads

> The syntax of the command is not correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @MitchWheat - he's shown code and given the exact text of the error he's getting (I only formatted to make it more obvious). What else are you expecting of him?

Comment: @SomethingDark: erm, checking his syntax himself.....

Comment: @SomethingDark yeah, the OP could have just commented out lines until it showed the error, then knowing what the problem is.

Comment: just removing `@echo off` should be enough to show the exact failing line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This segment works, use this as a basic - your set %% command is incorrect

```
@echo off

title HaxMenu

color 0c

cls

:menu

cls
Set /P first=Please enter color 1
Set /P second=Please enter color 2
set colorhax=%first%%second%
echo on
echo %colorhax%
color %colorhax%
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the simple mistake. I used to be better at batch, then I forgot almost everything I knew. I'm trying to pick it back up now.